# Cant get UIPageViewController to work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've been working on getting a UIPageViewController to work for quite some time, and the lack of result is starting to drive me nuts...

The following code is part tutorial (which I didn't get to work either) and part me. Right now I'm trying just trying to make each viewControllers view a single label, so that I can make sure it works before adding stuff.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

vcArray = [self createViewControllers:1];
NSLog(@"TEST1");


self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
self.pageController.delegate = self;
self.pageController.dataSource = self;
NSLog(@"TEST2 %@", vcArray);
[self.pageController setViewControllers:vcArray direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
[[pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
NSLog(@"TEST3");
[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
[[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
[pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
NSLog(@"TEST4");

}

- (NSArray *) createViewControllers:(NSInteger)ammount{
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i <= ammount; i++) {
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [PageContentViewController new];
    UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
    label.text = @"STRING";
    pageContentViewController.view = label;
    [array addObject:pageContentViewController];
}
return array;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:
                    (PageContentViewController *)viewController];
if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
    return nil;
}

index--;
return [vcArray objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:
                    (PageContentViewController *)viewController];
if (index == NSNotFound) {
    return nil;
}

index++;
if (index == [vcArray count]) {
    return nil;
}
return [vcArray objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(PageContentViewController *)viewController
{
return [vcArray indexOfObject:viewController.dataObject];
}
```

Can you see what I am missing?
I've been going through too many tutorials and stackoverflow questions which has left me only more confused...

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General tips:

Don't use `[PageContentViewController new]`, use `[[PageContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]`. Don't use `[UILabel new]`, use `[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGZeroRect]`.

Step through your code. Check for things that should be objects that are `nil`. Objective-C will silently allow things to be `nil`, even if you call methods on them!

Comment: So the code looks right in general? Ill do what you Said and report back!

Comment: It mostly looks right. You are doing a lot of things that should be done for you by other method calls (for example, only the middle line between TEST3 and TEST4 should be necessary). `setViewControllers:...` doesn't set all of the view controllers that should be browsable, just the visible view controllers. You will need to provide a data source eventually, and since you have set `self` to be your data source, you should return sensible values from the data source methods.

Comment: There's a thing I need to learn about too it seems. I have no idea of what a datasource is... Looking it up right away! If you could give a short explaination in a few words it would be really great! Also what do you mean by visible and browsable viewcontrollers? Whether or not they have a view?

Comment: By browsable I mean "all pages in a book" and by visible I mean the pages that are visible. A data source is an object telling another object what its data is. They are used so that you don't need to know everything about the data up front (like load all the pages of a book). The page view controller in particular needs only to know what the current page is, and then for a given page which pages surround it.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the guidance and for leading me in the right direction!